# Format number to put points on thousands

Tags: angular, format, pipe

I need to format a number to put points in the thousands, I need to format it using pipes in angular 2. Ejem: The number is 1983839 and the result must be 1.983.839 Any idea?

```
{{amount | number}}
```

Comment: what have to tried with pipes will be welcomed

Comment: This will be locale-dependent (here in en-GB we'd put 1,983,839). Angular already provides a pipe for it: [`DecimalPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe).

Comment: the locale is es-ES

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved the problem with this solution. I used the "DecimalPipe" pipe that provides angular.

I added the my locale in app.module in providers and imported "LOCALE_ID":

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

providers: [
  { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "es-ES" },
  ...
]
```

Then in my component i used the pipe "DecimalPipe" of angular:

```
component.ts:
   import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

component.html:
   {{fila.NumeroCopiasBN | Number:'1.0-0' }}
```

The parameter than i send to the pipe '1.0-0' is a string which has a following format:

{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}

Comment: You shouldn't need to `import` the pipe in the component to use it in the template. Also it's `number`, all lower case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok, I removed the import the pipe in the component. tnx

Answer (score 0):

Here the custom pipe

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import {DecimalPipe} from "@angular/common";

@Pipe({
    name: 'pointReplacer'
})
export class PointReplacerPipe extends DecimalPipe {

  transform(value: any, digits?: string): string {
        return super.transform(value, digits).replace(',', '.');


    }
}
```

and you need register custom pipe to your module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PointReplacerPipe],
  providers: [PointReplacerPipe]
})
```

Comment: Why do you think this needs a custom pipe? The thousands separator is just part of the locale configuration.

Comment: I resolved it adding the local to super in the constructor of de pipe, this way i avoid the replace. In the constructor of de pipe:     constructor() {
        super("es-ES");
    }

Comment: why is necesary register my custom pipe in providers of my module?

Comment: @ararb78 but again, if all you're doing is passing the locale to the parent, *you don't need a custom pipe*. The number will automatically get formatted to match the user's locale settings. And you *don't* need to register it as a provider unless you're planning to inject it somewhere.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes i don´t need a custom pipe because including the locale to app.module in providers "  { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "es-ES" }" and setting    {{fila.data | Number:'1.0-0' }} works.

Comment: @ararb78 then you should probably unaccept this answer and write one that reflects what you actually did, for the benefit of anyone else with a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

in your component right below mentioned code:

```
export class appComponent{
    num:number = 1983839;
    printNum:any;
    constructor() {
    this.test = this.num.toLocaleString('es-CO');
    console.log('printNum',this.printNum);
    }
}
```